# Распарсить JSON строку JavaScript

Tags: json, javascript, синтаксический-анализ

Вот такой вот возник вопрос, ранее я задавал вопрос [Залогиниться на сайте с помощью PhoneGap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116596/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-phonegap), сделал сам, теперь мне нужно строку которую я получаю на сервере распознать и распарсить. Пытался делать это при помощи функции $.parseJSON(data), но она мне ничего не выдает, выводит в лог ту же строку которую и получает, делал я это так:

```
var response_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$('#task1').html(response_obj.task1);
```

Есть какие нибудь идеи как можно еще распарсить эту строку, она приходит [в таком виде (ссылка)](https://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/login.php?who=testuser&pass=123456):

Comment: [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) функция JSON.parse()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш JSON не валидный. [Онлайн парсер](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Comment: даже если и не валидный, хоть что-то должно выводить? оно то не выводит...

Comment: не должно. смотрите консоль. до вывода скрипт просто не дойдет, все закончится на parseJSON с вызовом исключения.

Comment: > даже если и не валидный, хоть что-то должно выводить? оно то не выводит...

У вас все симптомы тяжелого заболевания под названием `PHP`.

Comment: Исправил, как теперь мне прочесть все айтемы и таски? Обычным так как я делаю не получается... Выдает undefined

Comment: С такими объектами, как у вас, работать неудобно. Неизвестно их количество и итерация по ним осложнена.

Лучше сделать вместо task_1, task_2... и item_1, item_2... соответствующие массивы tasks и items. См. [пример][1]. Тогда к ним удобно будет обращаться по индексу, а также сразу будут работать как надо $.each, $.map и т.д. сейчас если сделать $.each(response_obj.task_1.... туда попадут также другие поля объекта и нужно будет выяснять item это или нет.

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/J5dXh/

Comment: спасибо огромное, буду переделывать так как у вас в примере.

Answer (score 3):

ECMA-262 в 5 редакции включает функцию [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), которую поддерживает большинство современных браузеров. Попробуйте ее.

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"one":1, "two":2}');
```

Comment: то есть, eval('('+jsondata+')'); уже не стоит использовать?

Comment: [JSON.parse vs. eval()][1]. eval не безопасен в общем случае.

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval

Comment: @knes - *нормальные* люди eval, на прямую, не использовали его никогда ;)